Characterization of closed subspace of Hilbert spaces
Suppose you have a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and and a closed subspace $\mathcal{A}$ of that Hilbert space (thus it is a Hilbert space itself) and you have an orthonormal basis ${\{\phi_n \}}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ of $\mathcal{A}$.
Now if I have an element $f \in \mathcal{H}$ and I want to check whether it lies in $\mathcal{A}$, is it sufficient to show
$$\langle \phi_n, f \rangle \neq 0$$
for all $n \in \mathbb N$?

Take $\mathbb R e_1\subseteq A=\mathbb R e_1\oplus \mathbb R e_2 \subseteq \mathbb R^3 = H$ with the standard basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$. Then $\langle x e_1, e_2\rangle = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ but $xe_1 \in A$

Let $0\neq g\in A^\perp.$  and $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\phi_n+g.$ Then $\langle f,\phi_n\rangle =2^{-n}$ but $f\notin \mathcal{A}.$

No. But if $\{e_n\}_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{A}^{\perp}$ then a given $x\in \mathcal{H}$ lies in $\mathcal{A}$ if and only if $\langle e_n, x\rangle=0$ for all $n$.

This is not enough. It is false even in finite dimensions. If you have a plane in $\mathbf{R}^3$ and a vector which is neither in the plane or orthogonal to it, both projections on the plane are non-zero but the vector is not in the plane.
